# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL"

Tags: ios, http, request, send

Following problem: 
I get every time the error -1000, but really don't know what I can change. I've tried it with GET and another sending method. But I get every time the same error.
Does someone see my mistake?
thanks

```
NSString *get =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"mobileNumber=%@&deviceToken=%@",myMobileNumber,myDeviceToken];

[get stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myHomepage.net/login.php?%@",get]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];


NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseData = @"";
if ([response statusCode] ==200 )
{
    responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"---------responseData: %@",responseData);
    return responseData;
} else {
```

Comment: Best bet is that either `myMobileNumber` or `myDeviceToken` has a character in it that needs to be escaped that isn't.

Comment: Take a look at the traffic with a network analyzer such as Charles Proxy.

Comment: OK I found the mistake, its the number. It starts a new line after the number (also when I don't want it)

Answer (score 1):

You're not saving the result of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`. So, instead of:

```
[get stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You need:

```
get = [get stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

---

FYI, while the above fix will now successfully percent escape all characters not permitted within in a URL, there are actually some characters that are acceptable in a URL, but are not acceptable within a parameter value (e.g. a `+` which is interpreted as a space, or `&` which delineates parameters).

It is important to percent escape the values used in the parameters of the request in such a way that you escape not only those characters that are not legal in a URL, but also a few that are otherwise legal in a URL, but are not permitted within a parameter value.

Unfortunately the standard `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method does not do this. But the `CFURL` function `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` does. You apply this function to the individual parameter values. Here is a method that performs the necessary toll-free bridging between this function and ARC:

```
- (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}
```

You can use this method as follows:

```
NSString *get =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"mobileNumber=%@&deviceToken=%@", [self percentEscapeString:myMobileNumber], [self percentEscapeString:myDeviceToken]];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myHomepage.net/login.php?%@",get]];
```

This should correctly percent escape the parameter values of the string, regardless of the presence of these reserved characters, or not.